# Automating years

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PROPHIX_TIME, W_EXCH_RATE_YTD_ME_AVG_G.*, 'EUR' TO_CUR
FROM 
    W_MCAL_DAY_D
INNER JOIN 
    W_EXCH_RATE_YTD_ME_AVG_G ON MCAL_PERIOD = PD
WHERE 
    MCAL_YEAR IN (2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024)
```

Values are hardcoded in the above code in the `WHERE` clause.

If current date is 1st jan 2025, other year has to get added in where clause, like

```
WHERE MCAL_YEAR IN (2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024,  2025, .....so on)
```

Comment: Simply `WHERE MCAL_YEAR >= 2019`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a list of numbers. Filter the years with an upper- and lower-bound:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       PROPHIX_TIME,
       W_EXCH_RATE_YTD_ME_AVG_G.*,
      'EUR' TO_CUR
FROM   W_MCAL_DAY_D
       INNER JOIN W_EXCH_RATE_YTD_ME_AVG_G
       ON MCAL_PERIOD = PD
WHERE  MCAL_YEAR >= 2019
AND    MCAL_YEAR <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a row generator problem.

Presuming that starting year is 2019, then query (as today is 22nd of February **2024**, which is the `sysdate` (without time component)) you might use is

```
SQL> select 2019 + level - 1 as year
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= extract(year from sysdate) - 2019 + 1;

      YEAR
----------
      2019
      2020
      2021
      2022
      2023
      2024

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Or, in your case,

```
SELECT DISTINCT prophix_time, w_exch_rate_ytd_me_avg_g.*, 'EUR' to_cur
  FROM w_mcal_day_d INNER JOIN w_exch_rate_ytd_me_avg_g ON mcal_period = pd
 WHERE mcal_year IN (    SELECT 2019 + LEVEL - 1 AS year
                           FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 2019 + 1);
```

---

You never said why list begins with 2019; if that's *hardcoded*, then leave it as is. If not, fetch it, somehow.